# O Bootstrap tem código legado caso eu atualize a versão no meu projeto?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Eu posso atualizar o meu projeto que está utilizando [Bootstrap versão 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) para o [Bootstrap versão 4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/) atual? Existe um código legado que me assegure que não terei **GRANDES** problemas?

Comment: Depende do que você considera ***grandes problemas***. E esse *Bootstrap* que você comentou a versão mais atual é a 4.0 (em beta). Veja a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/247886/2) se não entendeu.

Comment: A principio não. Vai depender da estrutura do 3.3 para o 4.

Comment: Eu atualizei o projeto aqui na empresa para a vs 4.0 - beta a uns 2 meses e até agora nenhum problema/diferença que fosse relevante.